# Front end hangs on `NotebookRead` of `BoxObject`

Tags: front-end

I've got a simple way to hang the front end.

Here's how:

```
Graphics3D[
 {{Red, Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}]}},
 ImageSize -> 500,
 Epilog ->
  {
   AbsolutePointSize[10],
   Dynamic@Inset[
     NotebookRead@ParentBox@ParentBox@EvaluationBox[]
     ]
   }
 ]
```

I was able to track it down to the `NotebookRead`.
If we replace `NotebookRead@ParentBox@ParentBox@EvaluationBox[]` with `NotebookRead@ParentBox@EvaluationBox[]` there is no hang.
Similarly, going three boxes up doesn't hang.

This also isn't an issue in the main `Graphics3D`, since this doesn't crash

```
Graphics3D[
 Dynamic@Inset[
   Pane[
    NotebookRead@Nest[ParentBox, EvaluationBox[], 2],
    300
    ]
   ],
 ImageSize -> 500
 ]
```

and it clearly seems to be an issue with the way `Epilog` is arranged in the box layout.

Two questions:

1. does anyone know why?
2. is there a way to only extract the head of a `BoxObject` expression? That way at least I could try to bullet proof the process

Comment: Please include your version and platform to the post.